# Why I often got ExcBadAccess in this code:

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode5

I uses ARC

```
NSAttributedString * arString = [self asSchedule:arTimes];
self.lblTimeLeft.attributedText = arString;
```

Not much information is given. It goes straight to main

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        //int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
         int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([newIsiKotaAppDelegate class]));
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I manage to spot that the last code executed is this:
    self.lblTimeLeft.attributedText = arString;

I provided additional code to test things out

```
    NSAttributedString * arString = [self asSchedule:arTimes];
    self.lblTimeLeft.attributedText = arString;


    PO1(@"Hello World");
    while(false);// Error happen after this code is executed
}
```

The code is part of the routine that provides UITableViewCell to display. So error happen after

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;

    NSDictionary * rowDictionary = _marManagedObjectArray [row];

    BGCinemaScheduleCell * BCS = [[BGCinemaScheduleCell alloc]init];

    BCS.dicCinemaDictionary =rowDictionary;

    return BCS; //This is where the error happen
}
```

It seems that the NSAttributedString works fine till it's actually displayed or something.

The error seems to happen on

```
TAttributes::TAttributes(__CFDictionary const *)
```

The content of asSchedule is usual

```
-(NSAttributedString *) asSchedule:(NSArray *) arTimes
{
    NSMutableArray * timeBefore = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray * timeAfter = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString * strTime in arTimes) {

        NSDate * date = [NSDate dtWithCurrentDateAndProvidedTime: strTime];
        NSTimeInterval dblInterval =[date timeIntervalSinceNow];
        if (dblInterval>0)
        {
            [timeAfter addObject:strTime];
        }
        else{
            [timeBefore addObject:strTime];
        }
    }

    NSString * strTimeBefore = [timeBefore componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    NSString * strTimeAfter = [timeAfter componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

    NSString *yourString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", strTimeBefore, strTimeAfter];
                            // start at the end of strTimeBefore and go the length of strTimeAfter
    NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange([strTimeBefore length] + 1, [strTimeAfter length]);
    NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];
    [attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:boldFontName range:boldedRange];

    PO1(NSStringFromRange(boldedRange));
    PO1(@(attrString.length));
    return attrString;
}
```

Update:

I changed self.lblTimeLeft.attributedText = arString; to self.lblTimeLeft.attributedText = arString.copy; to no avail.

I wonder if this could be the problem:
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:boldFontName range:boldedRange];

I think the original sample use KCFont something instead of NSFontAttributeName

Comment: what is [self asSchedule:arTimes]??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

> I wonder if this could be the problem: [attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:boldFontName range:boldedRange];

Your code says:

```
NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
...
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:boldFontName range:boldedRange];
```

It should say:

```
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
...
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:boldFont range:boldedRange];
```

According to Table 1 of the docs (link below) and my own app code, you should be passing an NSFont not a font name.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004903-SW2

Comment: Yes, I figured that's what the problem was. Someone uses kcFont something in the sample and pass the font name. Because I do not know what kcFont is for, I changed that to NSFontAttributeName.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell from the code whether your project uses ARC or not, but it looks like your asSchedule method returns a string with a refcount of 0. It's up to you to retain a reference to that string, either old-school using the **retain** keyword (probably a bad idea) or by assigning it to a property declared with the **strong** keyword (or **retain**, if pre-ARC).

The best tool for debugging this stuff is Instruments, using the Zombies inspection. If I am right that you are trying to use the string after its refcount hits 0 and the memory has been released, you'll see the history of refcount increments and decrements pretty clearly.

Comment: I am using ARC. So that's like impossible. The one returned is NSMutableAttributedString though.

Answer (score -1):

Try alloc and initing the `Attributedstring` and then assign it to the `self.lblTimeLeft.attributedText`